# Multiple DNS Names for a public IP in Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm trying to setup a K8 ingress to route to multiple services based on the hostname. Like mentioned [here.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting)

In Azure, I'm able to map DNS name with Public IP using `az-cli` like this,

```
az network public-ip update --ids $PUBLICIPID --dns-name $DNSNAME
```

However, this command isn't letting me to add multiple DNS entries to the same publicIP.

What will be the right way to achieve this in Azure KS? Preferably using `az-cli` or some other `cli` tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you can assign multiple Azure managed DNS names to the same public IP, but you can use [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-cli#create-a-dns-record) or some external DNS provider to have as many CNAME records pointing to the same DNS record as you want to.

```
az network dns record-set cname set-record --resource-group myresourcegroup --zone-name contoso.com --record-set-name test-cname --cname www.contoso.com
```

an alternative would be to use [external dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) to let kubernetes manage it.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into this approach. If I'm taking the CNAME approach, will it affect the Azure managed DNS names? Ex: the existing one is in Azure managed DNS and if i add a CNAME record to a new one will they co-exist and work nicely?

Comment: yeah, because CNAME has nothing to do with the DNS name you assign to the public IP. that DNS is platform managed and the ones you assign via DNS are managed by you.